# Moving rows to and from Gridviews using .clone, .cloneNode and .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have two Gridviews, one loaded with data and the other not. When I double click an item from gvDisplayAvailItems, I want the row to go to gvDisplaySelectedItems, and vice-versa. The Grids are also multi-select, with a button allowing all selected items to be moved. gvDisplaySelectedItems differs by 1 additional input column.

AddDisplayParams() is called when the button is pressed.

```
function AddDisplayParams() {
            var rows = $("#gvDisplayAvailItems").find('tr.selected');
            rows.each(function (index, element) {
                element.classList.remove("selected");
                var newRow = element.cloneNode(true);
                newRow.appendChild(customIdTb.cloneNode(true));
                $("#gvDisplaySelectedItems").append(newRow);

                element.remove();
            });
        }
```

AddDisplayParam is called on double-click.

```
        function AddDisplayParam(param) {
            var newRow = param.clone(true);
            newRow.append(customIdTb.cloneNode(true));
            $("#gvDisplaySelectedItems").append(newRow);

            param.remove();
        }
```

And here is how I trigger the selection and double clicks.

```
$("#gvDisplaySelectedItems tr").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            });

            $("#gvDisplaySelectedItems tr").dblclick(function () {
                RemoveDisplayParam($(this));
            });

            $("#gvDisplayAvailItems tr").click(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("selected");
            });

            $("#gvDisplayAvailItems tr").dblclick(function () {
                AddDisplayParam($(this));
            });
```

When I both double click and mass select rows on gvDisplayAvailItems, the rows are moved to gvDisplaySelectedItems correctly. However, nothing is triggered for the functions of gvDisplaySelectedItems for rows that were added via AddDisplayParams. Those added by AddDisplayParam can be highligted, but when double clicked only append another textbox to the row in gvDisplaySelectedItems.

So it seems that .clone and .cloneNode are doing something very different here despite having basically the same function. Could someone please explain why one partially works, while the other does not? And also, why my functions for the second grid are not triggered upon single and double click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to try delegated event handlers.
E.g.

```
$("#gvDisplaySelectedItems").on("click", "tr", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

instead of

```
$("#gvDisplaySelectedItems tr").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

and so on for other event handlers.

[More info](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Regarding other improvements - you don't have to `clone()/append()/remove()` to move an element. Just doing `append()` to a new parent will effectively move it since an element can have only one parent each moment of time.

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/ycghhnww/)

Comment: But doing append() will carry the additional column with it. Is there a way to use append in this fashion while at the same time adding/removing that last <td>?

Comment: also the toggle functions aren't applying to the added rows when just using .append()

Comment: Here's an example of what I meant (don't know what grid you're using so just simple table here): http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/ycghhnww/ Regarding the ```<td>``` removal - in your Add function just find the last ```<td>``` in the ```param``` and ```remove()``` it, then do the ```append()```.